# Share SQLite with today extension not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, widget, today-extension

I am working on widget app. I am totally new to Today Extension. I want to share data between app and today extension. I have created one database. I have 4 tables in that database. I found this code to create database for App Groups :

```
NSString *appGroupId = @"group.appname";
    NSURL *appGroupDirectoryPath = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:appGroupId];
    dataBaseURL = [appGroupDirectoryPath  URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];
    NSLog(@"dataBaseURL %@", dataBaseURL);
```

It worked. My SQLite file has been created. But It does't show my tables. It shows empty database. I don't have any idea about it. Please help.

Comment: If you are creating new database then it will obviously empty.

Comment: Ohh.. Then how to use my created database in SQLIte tool? I already created 4 tables in that and added it to my project. @Lion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating new database then it will obviously empty.

first thing you can create data base with tables in objective c. there is no need to create database from outside the xcode and drag and drop yto xcode. you can refer this [techotopia tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_7_Application) for that.

Now if you put database in your main bundle by drag and drop then you can access that like,

```
 NSString *databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myDbName" ofType:@"sqlite"];
```

by this way you can get your database path. here pathforresource is your database name, i think `database` in your case and `oftype` is `extention`, i think `sqlite` in your case.

now you get path as string if you want it in url then you can convert it in url like,

```
  NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];

  or

  NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. It works in my app. But I want to share this same database with today extension. How can I do that?

Comment: you're welcome. :) I don't have much idea about today extension so google it for that you will find some solution for sure. if you feel this answer is helping then accept it so other people with similar problem can use it.

Comment: Finally.. As I asked in my question that its creating empty database. So I used that same code and then I created tables by coding.. And I solved my problem..!! So the line you wrote in your answer "you can create data base with tables in objective c." Helped me to solve it. :D .. Thanks ;)

Comment: @Monika Can you plz share your answer how you shared your tables from main app to today widget. Thanks